# In Angular 7 i got 404 Error When reload the page

Tags: angular7

i had Error 404 and lost my variables in Local Storage
my problem when happend then my application upload in server
in localhost i have not any problem

Comment: my problem was in routing module

Comment: routing in routing module or in app are the same(nicer to do it in separate module)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i add UseHash to my routing like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    { useHash: true }
  )
```

Comment: Also make sure "initialNavigation: false"

Comment: thanks  @Sasikumar